# php SESSION gets destroyed after redirection

Tags: php, session, xampp

I have a page where I set a value to a SESSION but when I redirect to another page 
ex. index.php that value I put to that SESSION doesn't exist anymore!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // this is the page where I set a value to a SESSION called var!
    $SESSION['var'] = "hello";

    if(isset($SESSION['var'])){
        echo "Yes it is";
        header("location: test.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo "No it isnt";
    }
?>
```

And this is the test.php where I get the SESSION undefined error!

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($SESSION['var'])){
        echo "Yes it is";
    }
    else {
        echo "No it isnt";
    }
?>
```

Ass you can see, I put session_start(); in both pages but still nothing!

Any help would be much appriciated,
thank you!

P.S Im using XAMPP

Comment: `$_SESSION`, note the `_`.

Answer (score 3):

To access session variables you need to access the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Change $SESSION to $_SESSION. Hope this helps.